# Microsoft-adal-angular6: UI freezes up when i am acquring token 1st time after deployment

Tags: angular, adal, adal.js, microsoft-adal-angular6

Once the application is loaded for first time after the deployment, the UI doesn't get loaded up. The api call is made and the data is passed to the front end. I could also log the output in console. But for some reason it doesnt bind it to ui and the UI is blank and all i see is loading icon. After refresh, everything works fine. This happens when im acquiring token for the first time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, I haven't found a satisfactory solution. You can find more info: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49099740/angular-5-adal-js-automatic-token-renew-in-load-angular-twice-or-more) and [here](https://github.com/benbaran/adal-angular4/issues/84)